# Singular differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory

The differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\,=\,\frac{A}{x}$$
has the general solution:
$$y\,=\,\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{c}
A\log(x)+B\\
A\log(-x)+C
\end{array} & \begin{array}{c}
x>0\\
x<0,
\end{array}\end{cases}$$
which can be written as $y(x)\,=\,A\log|x|+(B-C)\,\Theta(x)+C$.

Now, I would like to reproduce the same result by analyzing the $\epsilon\rightarrow0$ limit of the more general differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\,=\,\frac{A}{x+i\epsilon}.$$
The solution now is simply $y=A\ln(x+i\epsilon)$. How do I show that this reduce to the above solution when $\epsilon\rightarrow0$ ?

Comment: @Gonçalo: Yes, they are equivalent but the second version contains an additional parameter. What I would like to understand is if there is a relation like $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\ln(x+\epsilon)\,=\,\ln(x)+B\,\Theta(x)$

Comment: @Gonçalo: I edited, the question in a way such that the theta function will not emerge. Due to Sokhotski, $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\ln(x+i\epsilon)\,=\,\ln(x)+i\pi\Theta(-x)$, so this is almost fine, except that the coefficient of the Heaveside is imaginary.

Answer (score 1):

In complex analysis we learn that
$$
\ln(x+i\epsilon) = \ln\sqrt{x^2+\epsilon^2} + i\arctan\frac{\epsilon}{x} + i2\pi n,
$$
where $n\in\mathbb Z.$

When $\epsilon\to 0^+$ we have
$$
\ln(x+i\epsilon) \to \ln|x| + i\pi H(-x) + i2\pi n,
$$
where $H$ is the Heaviside step function.

When $\epsilon\to 0^-$ we instead have
$$
\ln(x+i\epsilon) \to \ln|x| - i\pi H(-x) + i2\pi n,
$$
i.e. with a minus sign instead of a plus sign in front of $i\pi H(-x).$

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148207/discussion-on-answer-by-md2perpe-singular-differential-equation); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.